# webpack resolve fallback doesn't work with `util/types` or `stream/web`

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to polyfill for `stream/web` and `util/types` but it seems `resolve.fallback` doens't understand dependencies with slashes in them.

For example, this configuration:

```js
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },

  plugins: [new NodePolyfillPlugin()],
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "util/types": false,
      "stream/web": false,
      perf_hooks: false,
      async_hooks: false,
      dns: false,
      tls: false,
      child_process: false,
      fs: false,
      net: require.resolve("net-websocket-polyfill"),
      diagnostics_channel: require.resolve("diagnostics_channel"),
      worker_threads: require.resolve("bthreads"),
    },
  },
};
```

still generates errors like this:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream/web'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util/types'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.

It's not a standard way, but I ended up solving the problem.

I hope it was helpful, even temporarily

1. Installing `util` package

```bash
yarn add util` or `npm install util
```

2. Copying `node_modules/support/types.js` to `node_modules/types.js`
3. Build